# The 'get' property does not exist on the 'any []' type

Tags: javascript, angular, vis.js, vis.js-network

I do not understand why I've got an error message, could anyone help me understand and sweat I can not do it again. I junior developer and I need your help
 i have this The 'get' property does not exist on the 'any []' type.

```js
let nodes = [];

nodes = [
  { id: 1, label: "PV Panels", color: "#3333ff" },
  { id: 2, label: "Gensets",color: "#cc00ff" },
  { id: 3, label: "Battery",color: "#ff0066" },
  { id: 4, label: "Wind Turbines",color: "#000099" }

];


net.on("selectNode", function (params) {
      var selectedNode = nodes.get(params.nodes[0]);
  alert("You've selected node: " + selectedNode.label);
  });
```

With some modification the get() works.

```js
let nodes = new vis.DataSet ([
      { id: 1, label: "PV Panels", color: "#3333ff" },
      { id: 2, label: "Gensets",color: "#cc00ff" },
      { id: 3, label: "Battery",color: "#ff0066" },
      { id: 4, label: "Wind Turbines",color: "#000099" }

    ]);

    net.on("selectNode", function (params) {
      var selectedNode = nodes.get(params.nodes[0]);
  alert("You've selected node: " + selectedNode.label);
      
  });
```

After this fact can you tell me how I display its information in an input.

I thought about using a getElementById.

What do you think?

Comment: It seems `nodes` has been typed as an `any[]`, but arrays don't have a `.get` function

Comment: Can you post the part of your code where `nodes` is defined? Also @KrishnaRathore, what would that change?

Comment: I add the part of the missing code. it's a angular app

Comment: @KirikKhu Can you explain what you want the `.get` function to do? What is the value of `params.nodes[0]`?

Comment: I do not know if this is the correct way to get the elements in the table and click to fill input fields with. I'm using vis.js

Answer (score 0):

The `get` method doesn't exist on an array. You might want to use the `find` method

More information can be found here: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_find.asp

To show the result in an input field:

```
document.getElementById('yourInputFieldID').value = selectedNode
```

Assuming selectedNode variable is a string.

Comment: I understood thanks for this information. i made some modification